# CLOS like object model for PHP

Tags: php, oop, moose, clos

I have returned to php development from [Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/) and I really miss CLOS like object model for php. Is there some kind of syntaxtic sugar which would allow me to write **less code** in php when dealing with objects?

Just to stress this requirement a bit more. I don't want to write one thing in several places. I can live with part of code being generated automatically, but in the code that I have to see to develop I don't want to see redundant information which is just clutter (think: LISP macro if you really need more analogy). So this part can be also called DSL if that makes more sense.

I would love to have at least **roles** (mixins), and some kind of **introspection** without re-inventing the weel. Code generators and auto-loaders might be one way to solve at least part of this problem.

p.s. For JavaScript there is [Joose](http://code.google.com/p/joose-js/), so similar API would be very useful.

Comment: Aside from automatic getters and setters, what other aspects of CLOS would you like to see?

Much of what I was able to read about CLOS in the last 5 minutes won't be achievable in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also new project http://github.com/huberry/phuby which implements roles in php!

Answer (score 2):

There are no mixins in php yet but there is an RFC for traits which will work roughly the same. http://wiki.php.net/rfc/traits

Using overloading for __call can allow you to dispatch methods to other classes and have it look like a mixin.

Comment: Is there any hope to have it in official php any time soon?

Answer (score 1):

The [Symfony project has a mechanism for mixins](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/17-Extending-Symfony), allowing aspect oriented programming like in CLOS. Personally, I don't like this kind of hacking in userland spacee (At least not with PHP). I think you would be better off using the features that the language provides, and perhaps wait for something like traits to (maybe) make its way into the language.

Comment: While it does seem like a nice framework, it fails initial requirement of less code, especially __construct in example that you linked. After few readings it still seems completely redundant to me.

Comment: I don't particularly like it either, but it's there, if you want it.